# Design database for storing files

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and SQL. I'm working on small application which is used to store files. So far I created these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE KNOWLEDGEBASE(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 NAME TEXT,
 SHORT_DESCRIPTION TEXT,
 DESCRIPTION TEXT,
 CONTENT TEXT,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE KNOWLEDGEBASE

ALTER TABLE KNOWLEDGEBASE ADD CONSTRAINT KEY9 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

-- TABLE KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES

CREATE TABLE KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 DOC_ID INTEGER,
 FILE BYTEA
)
;

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP4 ON KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES (DOC_ID)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES

ALTER TABLE KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES ADD CONSTRAINT KEY10 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

-- CREATE RELATIONSHIPS SECTION ------------------------------------------------- 

ALTER TABLE KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES ADD CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP4 FOREIGN KEY (DOC_ID) REFERENCES KNOWLEDGEBASE (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
```

I have several questions:

1. Is this foreign key correct between the two tables? I want to have one entry in table KNOWLEDGEBASE and multiple files attached to this entry.
2. How I can insert with one SQL query one row in table KNOWLEDGEBASE and multiple files in KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES?

Comment: May I know why I get negative feedback?

Comment: Did you know that PostgreSQL have Large Object suport? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html. And did you know that PosgreSQL JDBC diver supports large object? https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/index.html. I think that  native large object support is better for storing files in database that using bytea type

Comment: Do you mean OID data type or something else?

Comment: I mean what the documentations says. Did you read it?

Comment: I checked it quickly but it looks like there are C/C++ functions. I use Java

Comment: the second link is for Java. There are two java classes LargeObject and LargeObjectManager. Did you read it?.

Comment: Yes, before that what data type you recommend me to use for large files?

Comment: I recommended you to use PostgreSQL Large Objects facility to store files. You don't need a table with a bytea column to store the file content. You create a LargeObject that is stored in a specital table. When you create a large object you get an indentifier that you store in another table, and you use that identifier later to access the content.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Do you have experience with this solution on some project?

Answer (score 1):

re 1: yes the foreign key is correct.

re 2: In general I would recommend to use multiple statements in a single transaction. That is usually easier to handle:

```
begin transaction;
insert into knowledgebase 
    (id, name, short_description, description, content, last_updated, created)
  values
    (42, 'First document', 'a short one', 'a longer description', 'Not much to say', current_date, current_date);

insert into knowledgebase_files 
  (id, doc_id, file)
values
  (42, 1, ...),
  (42, 2, ...),
  (42, 3, ...);

commit;
```

If you **really** need to do this in a single SQL statement, you need to use a common table expression:

```
with new_kb as (
  insert into knowledgebase 
    (id, name, short_description, description, content, last_updated, created)
  values
    (42, 'First document', 'a short one', 'a longer description', 'Not much to say', current_date, current_date)
  returning id
)
insert into knowledgebase_files 
  (id, doc_id, file)
values
  ( (select id from new_kb), 1, ...),
  ( (select id from new_kb), 2, ...),
  ( (select id from new_kb), 3, ...)
;
```

Note that it depends on your SQL client or programming language how exactly you provide the data for the file (that's why I just wrote `...` at the places where you need to supply the value).

If you are using JDBC, you need to use a `PreparedStatement` and e.g. `setBinaryStream()` to transmit the contents of a file.

You probably want to make `knowledgebase.id` a `serial` column, or at least create a sequence for the IDs in there.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I'm going to use Java with PostgreSQL

Comment: What do you mean by `knowledgebase.id a serial column`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: By the way is there anything similar to serial in Oracle?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAECCFH